# Inserting apostrophe values in sqlite error

Tags: android

I cant a able to insert apostrophe character in sqlite . I tried this way what many says in forum is replace " ' " with " ' ' "

```
String replace=replaceString.replace("'"," ''") but after using this method too gives insert error.
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use

```
String replace = replaceString.replace("'","\'");
```

This will insert the apostrophe into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use ' in a string?

If so you can do this

"insert into my_table set myvalue = 'My dog\'s bone' where id = 5"